# slice function applied on undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react app where when I type some text in the input field, the field should be matched with the list of cities.
I created an action and take two inputs (list and city), I applied `list.slice()` and checked the value. when I enter another character in the input field its shows `error` that slice is applied on `undefined`.

```
//app.js
inputHandler = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let val = event.target.value;
  this.props.onCitySearch(this.props.cityList, val);
};
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    cityList: state.cities.citylist,
    citiesSearched: state.cities.citySearched
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onFetch: () => dispatch(actions.fetchCities()),
    onCitySearch: (list, city) => dispatch(actions.citySearched(list, city))
  };
};
//actions.js
export const fetchCities = () => dispatch => {
  fetch("http://localhost:8000/cities")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      return dispatch({
        type: "FETCHCITIES",
        cities: data
      });
    });
};

export const citySearched = (list, city) => dispatch => {
  console.log(list);
  const cities = list.filter(c => {
    return c.name.toLowerCase().includes(city.toLowerCase());
  });
  localStorage.setItem("cities", JSON.stringify(cities));
  return dispatch({
    type: "CITIESSEARCHED",
    city: cities
  });
};
//citiesReducer
const initialState = {
  citylist: [],
  citySearched: []
};

const citiesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCHCITIES":
      return {
        ...state,
        citylist: action.cities
      };
    case "CITIESSEARCHED":
      return {
        citySearched: action.city
      };
    default:
      return {
        ...state
      };
  }
};
export default citiesReducer;
```

Comment: What value doe you get in `console.log(list);`

Comment: when u type the second type whats list is printing basically console.log(list)

Comment: can you try to reproduce the issue and share the link in stack snippets or codesandbox it will be helpful to answer, also please add the mapDispatch , mapState and the reducer code . I feel somewhere in cityList array you are overriding the values so it becomes undefined

Comment: in console.log(list) firstly i get all the name of the cities and when i type second character in the input field it throws the error of undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Use *.filter* instedof *.slice*

```
const citySearched= (list, city)=> (dispatch)=>{
  const cities = list.filter((xyz) => {
      return xyz.toLowerCase().includes(city.toLowerCase());
  });
  localStorage.setItem("cities",JSON.stringify(cities));
  return dispatch({
      type: 'CITIESSEARCHED', city: cities
  });
};
```